# How to skip setTimeout in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a script that should call another JavaScript function every 8 seconds. However, in some cases, I need to skip the `setTimeout` function that takes care of the 8 second delay (it is a slider and depending on what the user click, I need to get to a specific slide right away). Is this possible in JavaScript?

So for example, based on what the user clicks, I might want to immediately execute `switchBullets(4); switchNews("Title 4", "image4.jpg", "image4Logo.jpg", "")`, regardless where the animation is at the moment.

The script looks like this:

```js
function animateNews() {
    $(window).load(function() {
    
    switchBullets(1);
    switchNews("Title 1", "image1.jpg", "image1Logo.jpg", "");
    setTimeout(function() { switchBullets(2); switchNews("Title 2", "image2.jpg", "image2Logo.jpg", "") 
    setTimeout(function() { switchBullets(3); switchNews("Title 3", "image3.jpg", "image3Logo.jpg", "") 
    setTimeout(function() { switchBullets(4); switchNews("Title 4", "image4.jpg", "image4Logo.jpg", "") 
    setTimeout(function() { animateNews(); 
                          }, 8000);
                          }, 8000);
                          }, 8000);
                          }, 8000);
    }
)};
```

Comment: why don't you use `setInterval`?

Comment: Put each of your `setTimeout()` sets of actions in its own function and you can then call that function any time.  If you save the return value from `setTimeout()`, you can cancel that timer at any time too.  So, I assume you would cancel the relevant timer, then call the relevant function directly.

Comment: That sounds good jfriend00, but I'm not sure how to do that. If I put these actions into a function, how do I know with what parameters I should call the function if they would differ by title, image, etc. - all the ways that occur to me end with code duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate your data from your logic. Use `setInterval()` instead to make it run forever. When the user clicks, call `click()` and the setInterval will be cancelled.

```
var timerId;
var data = [
    {title: 'Title 2', img1: 'image2', img2: 'image2Logo.jpg', other: ''},
    {title: 'Title 3', img1: 'image3', img2: 'image3Logo.jpg', other: ''},
    {title: 'Title 4', img1: 'image4', img2: 'image4Logo.jpg', other: ''}
];
$(window).load(function() {
    switchBullets(2);
    switchNews("Title 2", "image2.jpg", "image2Logo.jpg", "");
    timerId = beginSlider();
});

function beginSlider() {
    var i = 1;
    return setInterval(function () {
        switchBullets(i+2);
        switchNews(data[i].title, data[i].img1, data[i].img2, data[i].other);
        if (i === 2) { i = 0; }
        else { i += 1; }
    }, 8000);
}
function click(j) {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    switchBullets(j+2);
    switchNews(data[j].title, data[j].img1, data[j].img2, data[j].other);
    // could start slider again after 8 sec.
    // timerId = beginSlider();
}
```

Comment: this sounds like exactly what I've been looking for! Thanks! But I'm still getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined at switchNews(data[i].title, data[i].img1, data[i].img2, data[i].other);

Comment: Make sure i is equal to 0, 1, or 2. Also make sure you got the latest revision, cuz I made an edit :/

Comment: Value of i is 0,1 or 2, but even if I set it to 1 manually in switchNews argument, I still get the cannot read property title of undefined... I have to say im puzzled

Comment: I also found out that the problem really is that beginSlider doesn't see into "data", since putting data definition into beginSlider makes it accessible by the method (while this would cripple the click method). Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Solved in the end by moving data into beginSlider and removing "var" in the declaration, thusly making data global. also, if data is global, is does not work when it is called data, so I renamed it and it all works fine. Thumbs up, Dingalingalingalong!